# How to create an image with gradient where top has opacity 100% and bottom with opacity 0%?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, image

So I have an image (Link to image=> https://i.stack.imgur.com/YelUE.jpg) that has a gradient below it (background of the body).
Currently, the image has a fade to black gradient, but I want the image to fade to the given gradient.

Basically, a way to have the image go from opacity 100% on top and opacity 0% on the bottom.

```
// HTML
<div className="h-screen w-full gradient-bg hero-image z-10>
        <Image
            src={event.name_image.url}
            alt={event.Name}
            layout="fill"
            className="bg-top bg-cover object-cover"
          />
</div>
```

```
// CSS
.gradient-bg div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.gradient-bg div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%
  );
}
```

If there is some other way to achieve the same so the image fades to the background, that can also work.
If there is a JS/React library which can help me achieve this, that may also work.

PS. background in my project is dynamic (gradient colors change every few seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the purpose of mask:

```css
.gradient-bg {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
  display:inline-block;
}

.gradient-bg img {
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(white 50%, transparent);
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-bg">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/300">
</div>
```